# How to make nested for loop over two integer ranges?

Tags: sml

I want to replicate a function like -

```
for i in range(10): 
    for j in range(10): 
        do something with i, j
```

Is there a easy way to do this in SML?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do this, but you should consider whether you really want to just `do something with i, j` and discard the result. That is inherently imperative logic, not really idiomatic Standard ML.

But if this is really what you want, then there are a few ways. Here's an imperative one:

```
let val i = ref 0
 in while !i < 10 do
    ( let val j = ref 0
       in while !j < 10 do
          ( do something with i, j
          ; j := !j + 1
          )
      end
    ; i := !i + 1
    )
end
```

And here's a more-idiomatic one:

```
let val range0To9 = List.tabulate (10, fn i => i)
 in List.app range0To9 (fn i => List.app range0To9 (fn j => do something with i, j))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what it is you want to *do*.

Do you want to produce a side-effect, like print something, for each *(i, j)*?

```
fun appulate (n, f) =
  let fun go i = if i < n then (f i; go (i+1)) else ()
  in go 0 end

val show = Int.toString
val _ = appulate (10, fn i =>
          appulate (10, fn j =>
            print ("(" ^ show i ^ ", " ^ show j ^ ")\n")))
```

Or do you want to produce a result value? Is this value a list, or something else?

As a concrete example, there's a Q&A on the [Pythagorean triplets in SML](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179054/porting-haskell-list-comprehensions-to-standard-ml). It asks how one might port a piece of Haskell code that uses list comprehensions to Standard ML which doesn't feature list comprehensions. You could make a very similar case with Python 3; its `range()` function does not produce a *list*, but rather an object that can be iterated.

Whereas SML's `List.tabulate` actually does produce a list, making it less memory efficient if you're going to discard or filter that list immediately afterwards. The Q&A I linked to discusses readability and efficiency for a specific case of *doing something* on the Cartesian product of three integer ranges (namely finding the ones that are Pythagorean triplets).

Maybe if you gave a concrete example of *doing something*, you'd get a better response. :-)

Feel free to revise your question with a concrete example.